# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_EMPLOYEE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to update the record but it is showing that "violation of primary key constraint, can't insert duplicate key in object/table".
This error sounds like "ADD EMPLOYEE block" is called while i am updating the record.

If i drop primary key it inserts another record(updated) instead of updating the previous one!
Note: Already read many questions to solve it!

```
static public void UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMPLOYES"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    using (conn)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateEmployeeRecord", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8).Value = employee.EmployeeID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.FirstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastNmae", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value =     employee.LastName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.Email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telephone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.Telephone;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

static public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMPLOYES"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    using (conn)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddNewEmployee", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8).Value = employee.EmployeeID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.FirstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastNmae", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.LastName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.Email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telephone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = employee.Telephone;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //(X) Exception is here
        }
    }
```

Procedure used

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEmployeeRecord]
(
    @EmployeeID NVARCHAR(8),@FirstName  NVARCHAR(50),
@LastNmae NVARCHAR(50),@Email NVARCHAR(50),
@Telephone Nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [DBO].[EMPLOYEE] SET  FirstName = @FirstName,
            LastName = @LastNmae, Email = @Email, Telephone = @Telephone
        WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID 
    END
```

I am expecting that the record will be updated but it is some kind of violation of primary key constraints.

Comment: Sounds like your parent code is calling the wrong method.

Comment: No, it works! but i can't update record if there is primary key,  on removing primary key it gives me the update in the form of another new record!

Comment: What happens if you just run your stored procedure manually from SSMS?

Comment: @spodger Working in ssms

Comment: Well try debugging your code and make sure it's calling the right method because that doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

In procedure @LastNmae is the error used @LastName but no affects

Comment: The parameter may be misspelled but it's consistent so should still work.

Comment: Could you say that in english please?

Comment: @FalcoGer dear a parameter was misspelled but it was not the problem